Smarty 4.5.2 template generation causes PHP Warning: Array to string conversion error
PHP 8.2
       $utility_links = array( 0 => array('name'     => 'Member Login',
                                          'hrefpage' => 'login_page.php'));

TEMPLATE:
{section name="i" loop=$utility_links}
        <a href="{$utility_links[i].hrefpage}"> {$utility_links[i].name} </a> |
{/section}

This has been working fine previously, but since conversion to Smarty 4.5.2
I get:
Array to string conversion in /var/www/members.austintgca.com/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/1ca2fef31b64289057db4688371cb3bf741c93cd_0.file.static_main_page.tpl.php on line 35
I have just about beat the old noggin to death but I don't see the error:
From TEMPLATE GENERATED LINE 35
$_smarty_tpl->_subTemplateRender("file:utility_links_nav.tpl", $_smarty_tpl->cache_id, $_smarty_tpl->compile_id, 0, $_smarty_tpl->cache_lifetime, array('utility_links'=>((string)$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['utility_links']->value)), 0, false);


(string)$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['utility_links']->value - this, perhaps? What do you get with var_dumping it?

Not quite sure how to accomplish that since that code is generated by smarty on each invocation?

I'm guessing that you have $smarty->assign('utility_links',$utility_links); somewhere in your code. Can you var_dump right after that?

array (
0 =>
array (
'name' => 'Member Login',
'hrefpage' => 'login_page.php',
),
)

By chance has the scope for variables changed since 4.1.0?

I'm looking at the documentation, and I don't see any mention of it (4.x and 5.x are the same in that regard, at least according to the docs).
